# Chrome Web Serial no compatible device found on MacOS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-serial-api

I am trying to connect to an ANT+ usb stick using Web Serial API in Google Chrome.
On linux (Ubuntu) it works out of the box, but on MacOS (v12.1) the device doesn’t show up into the search box. It does show up when using the `web-serial-polyfill`, but it is unfinished and missing features, and since the `navigator.serial` is present I wish to avoid using the polyfill.

`var port = await navigator.serial.requestPort({ filters: [{ usbVendorId: 4047 }]});`

Gets me ‘No compatible device found’. Requesting without params shows other devices, but not the ANT+ stick.

Any ideas why is that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.